# JavaScript array method chaining

Tags: javascript, arrays, chaining

I'm trying to learn array method chaining and am using a basic example - https://jsbin.com/surizinifi/edit?js,console

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Butters',
    age: 3,
    type: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lizzy',
    age: 6,
    type: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'Red',
    age: 1,
    type: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'Joey',
    age: 3,
    type: 'dog'
  },
];


const ages = data
  .filter(animal => animal.type === 'dog')
  .map(animal => animal.age * 7)
  .reduce((sum, animal) => sum + animal.age)

console.log('ages', ages);
```

I'm getting "NaN" returned as a posed to a numeric output (e.g. 84). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In your `reduce` you don't gen an `animal` object but `animalAge` number - the `map` from the previous step gives you an array of numbers.

Comment: You could have debugged this problem very easily.

Answer (score 1):

The method `.map()` returns the array of the number, there is no property to sum

```
.reduce((sum, age) => sum + age)
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Butters',
    age: 3,
    type: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lizzy',
    age: 6,
    type: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'Red',
    age: 1,
    type: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'Joey',
    age: 3,
    type: 'dog'
  },
];


const ages = data
  .filter(animal => animal.type === 'dog')
  .map(animal => animal.age * 7)
  .reduce((sum, age) => sum + age, 0)

console.log('ages', ages);
```

Answer (score 1):

By the mapping, you get an array of numbers and then you need no property for summing.

A good idea is to use a start value for the accumulator and prevent to use both first values of the array in the first loop.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Butters',
    age: 3,
    type: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lizzy',
    age: 6,
    type: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'Red',
    age: 1,
    type: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'Joey',
    age: 3,
    type: 'dog'
  },
];


const ages = data
  .filter(animal => animal.type === 'dog')
  .map(animal => animal.age * 7)
  .reduce((sum, age) => sum + age, 0)

console.log('ages', ages);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass on a new array of animals to the reduce-method where each animal's age was multiplied by 7:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Butters',
    age: 3,
    type: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lizzy',
    age: 6,
    type: 'dog'
  },
  {
    name: 'Red',
    age: 1,
    type: 'cat'
  },
  {
    name: 'Joey',
    age: 3,
    type: 'dog'
  },
];


const ages = data
  .filter(animal => animal.type === 'dog')
  .map(animal => ({
    ...animal,
    age: animal.age * 7
   }))
  .reduce((sum, animal) => sum + animal.age, 0)

console.log('ages', ages);
```